# Installing a private package to @types - TypeScript & NPM

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a repo that's comprised only of an `index.d.ts` file (TypeScript definition file) that I want to share among a number of repos I have. The only declaration in the type definition file is an interface like so:

```
interface MyInterface {
    thisSuperCoolFunction(): void;
}
```

Unfortunately, the definition repo and all other repos I'm using are private. Is it possible to submit a private npm typings project to `@types` so that installing it will just work but also not expose it to anyone else?

Note: Not the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) repo, only `@types` on npm.

Answer (score 12):

You don't have to send your typings anywhere. You can use [git url as dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies) or [local path](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths)

---

Assuming you want to create `@types/secret-library`. And your types are in file `index.d.ts`.

Create `package.json` with `@types/secret-library` as a package name

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "@types/secret-library",
  "private": true,
  "types:" "index.d.ts"
}
```

### *git url*

Push both `index.d.ts` and `package.json` to some repo e.g. `git.acme.com/secret-project.git`.

Now in your other project you can reference this repository as a dependency

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "doom-machine",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies":{
      "@types/secret-library": "git://git.acme.com/secret-project.git"
  }
}
```

### *local path*

If both `index.d.ts` and `package.json` are in directory `/home/evil-genius/doom-saucer`

You can reference this path as a dependency

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "doom-machine",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies":{
      "@types/secret-library": "file:/home/evil-genius/doom-saucer"
  }
}
```

Comment: Git url solution has some limitation in versioning - you cannot use semver version ranges. You may point to specific tags or specific branches, but not version ranges. You may work around it by manually maintaining branches for each usable range (1.x, 1.1.x, 1.2.x, 1.3.x, 2.x, 2.1.x, 2.2.x, ...).